# How do I make a JQuery close a button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello I am trying to make a JQuery code to close my error button but I am having problems doing so, if you could help out thank you. Please take it easy on me since I am just learning the ropes for JQuery.

This is my php/html code

```
<?php if(isset($template->form->error)) { ?>
                <div class="flash" style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>
                <div class="alert alert-error">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</button>
                <h4>Warning!</h4>
                <?php echo $template->form->error; ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

I am trying to make it so when you click the (x)     ×

the error pop-up to go away, I tried this JQuery code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$(".close").remove(); // The close is the class and not the id (Thank you jsexpert and Darren)
});
});
</script>
```

Could it be, because of my login submit? Here is my login button/ login submit

```
<div><input class="btn btn-primary" name="login" type="submit" value="Login"></div>
```

Sorry I wasn't making myself clear. http://prntscr.com/433iza the warning! is what I want to get rid of by click the x button to the right. All $(".close").remove(); did was this http://prntscr.com/433lfh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is your problem:

```
$("#close").remove();
```

should be:

```
$(".close").remove(); // The close is the class and not the id
```

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't clear on what I was asking for when I asked my question, your code did work but just got rid of my x (:

Comment: you can use jquery hide on your top most element of the dialog that you created.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much jsexpert. Have a wonderful day if its daytime where you are at (:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using bootstrap? (*Correct me if I'm wrong*)?

If that is the case, you want your bind to use [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$(".close").trigger("click");
```

Also the other issue was that you're button has a `class (.)` and **not** an `id (#)`.

If that isn't the case, you're better off binding to the specific button:
i.e-

```
$("button.close").click(function(){
    $('#close').remove();
});
```

---

Also, I don't see an element with `#close` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong, as others have pointed out. But here is another way to do it.

```
$(function(){
    $( ".close" ).click(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $( this ).hide();
    });
});
```